Attempting to simplify Fiege-Fiat-Shamir Identification
My understanding of the Fiege-Fiat-Shamir protocol, sourced from "RSA and Public-Key Cryptography" by Richard A. Mollin is as below:

A third party chooses two large primes $p$ and $q$, sharing $n = pq$.
Alice has a secret value $s_a$ and shares a number $t_a = s_a^2 \mod n$.
Alice picks a random $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and sends $w = m^2 \mod n$ to Bob.
Bob picks a challenge $c \in \{0, 1\}$ and sends that to Alice.
Alice computes $r = ms_a^c \mod m$ and sends that to Bob.
Bob computes $r^2 = m^2s_a^{2c}$, and he can compare that to the publicly known $wt_a^2$, which should be identical if Alice does indeed know $s_a$. The security of this protocol is based on the fact that it is difficult to solve quadratic modular congruences with unfactored moduli.

My text elaborates that there is a method that an attacker can use to impersonate Alice with a 50% success rate, so this is done $a$ times and the probability that this works becomes $2^{-a}$.

If my understanding of this is correct, then one could use a similar protocol, but without the 50% chance of failure:

As before, a third party selects $p$ and $q$, sharing $n = pq$.
Alice picks a random $m$ and sends $w = m^2 \mod n$ to Bob.
Alice sends $r = ms_a \mod n$ to Bob.
Bob computes $r^2 \mod n$ and confirms that it's equal to $mt_a$.

Again, because neither $w$ nor $t_a$ are easy to compute, this seems secure.
I assume that this doesn't work. Why not? Why does Fiege-Fiat-Shamir require that Bob send a challenge?

I assume that step 4 of your protocol is to check that $r^2=wt_a\mod n$ otherwise the correctness is untrue.
If this is the case, your protocol allows an adversary to impersonate Alice with 100% success.
The adversary selects a random $r$ and squares it to produce a value $x=r^2\mod n$. They divide $x$ by $t_a$ mod $n$ to get a fake $w=x/t_a$ value and send this to Bob.
Alice then sends their random $r$ value and Bob can confirm that $r^2=x=wt_a\mod n$ even though the adversary has no knowledge of $s_a$.
The FFS protocol is set-up because the adversary is in a position to fake the protocol if he knowns that the choice will be $c=0$ and if he knows that the choice will be $c=1$ but not both. Provided that the adversary cannot advantageously predict the choice of $c$ and it is selected with probability 0.5,  the adversary can therefore only fake the protocol 50% of the time.

Am I understanding correctly that the challenge bit c is selected so that r cannot be decided in advance by Alice, thereby undermining the 'attack' you outline? Thanks for this explanation, it's very helpful!

@deeplyconfused That's correct.
